# Calling functions in SKAction.run doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
func experiment() {
    print ("I am inside the function")
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    SKAction.run({self.experiment()})
}
```

Don't see the print happening.

Answer (score 1):

That works, it will do nothing.  All you are doing in that case is creating an action that runs a function. Since it does nothing, the action is released.

Now what you meant to do was run the action on the scene

```
run(SKAction.run({experiment()}))
```